# Gradle slows down computer during findbugs analysis of Java project

Tags: java, gradle, findbugs

I'm using gradle 2.4 for a multi-project written in Java which has abount 15000 lines of code in 5 projects and i'm using Windows 7. I'm using the findbugs plugin in every sub-project.

The build itself is fast (enough) but while findbugs is running the reactivity of my PC is very bad. Most time the mouse hangs, opening websites takes a lot of time, music shutters, video hangs, etc.

If i reduce the priority of the corresponding java-process, everything is fine. For linux i found this https://askubuntu.com/questions/469709/gradle-compiling-slows-down-my-computer . I tried the suggested -PtaskThreads=x option, but that didn't help.

Is there a way to set the priority of the java-process which does the findbugs stuff to 'idle' or 'background' programmaticaly? Preferable with pure gradle options since i don't want to use some tools like CPULimit.

Comment: Consider instead running Findbugs on a CI and ErrorProne as part of the normal build.

Comment: You can also change the '[effort](https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.plugins.quality.FindBugsExtension.html#org.gradle.api.plugins.quality.FindBugsExtension:effort)' for local builds. Unfortunately I can't find a direct answer to your specific question. It could be raised as a feature request.

Comment: @BenManes I'm using Jenkins as a CI. Don't care if gradle slows the specific node down. In my case there's a special release task in the build.gradle which builds everything, performs some checks (i.e. the findbugs stuff) and if everything is OK, the artifacts are uploaded to a maven repository. This release-task should not be run on a CI in my opinion. And i realy don't want to skip findbugs when building and publishing a release.

Comment: I do think releasing from a CI is a good practice. You might be able to launch Findbugs using the `ant` task and set the `nice` level to run in low priority.

Comment: Seconded, the release task (perhaps _especially_ the release task) should be run in CI if you can, because it eliminates the risk that you forget to run any steps in the release sequence.